# SwiftUI - iOS 14.5 Update navigation bar issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

I updated my app to iOS 14.5 and suddenly a navigation problem showed up. I didn't had this issue in iOS 14.4 or lower.

I made a small new program to show the issue. When I clicked on the navigationLink (without scrolling down) the navigation bar in the second view isn't visible and the pictures will be shown in the top. When I scroll down a little the navigation bar is directly visible in the top of the second view. How can I move to the second view without showing the navigation bar directly at the top? It should only visible when I scrolling down.

Please could you give me a help on this?

Thanks in advance!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                List {
                    NavigationLink(destination: navigationbarIssue()){
                        Text("Navigation image")
                    }
                    Image("car")
                        .resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.85, height: 600, alignment: .center)
                        .scaledToFill()
                    }
                
                Text("Hello, Do you like this mini car!")
                    .padding()
                }
            .navigationTitle("Car")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct navigationbarIssue: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                VStack{
                    Image("car")
                       .resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width * 1.11, height: geo.size.height * 1.11)
                       .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
                       .offset(x: -20, y: -166)
                       .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("Question: What's the topspeed of this mini car?")
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picture: Show navigation issue]

I added two pictures:
First one: parent view - without navigationbar pop out.
Second one: parent view - navigationbar pop out (scroll down).
I like to have always only the car picture on the top (on the edge) and when you scroll down the navigationbar appears.

[[image: Navigationbar issue][1]]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `navigationbarIssue` thinks it should have a Large Title style navigation bar, which is transparent until scrolled. You want to add `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)` so that it has a inline navigation style.

```
struct navigationbarIssue: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                VStack{
                    Image("car")
                       .resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width * 1.11, height: geo.size.height * 1.11)
                       .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
                       .offset(x: -20, y: -166)
                       .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("Question: What's the topspeed of this mini car?")
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("The car") /// might want to add a title too
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) /// here!
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Navigation bar stays in pushed navigationbarIssue view]

Comment: navigationBarTitle Is being [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitle(_:)-6p1k7) [func navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(_ displayMode)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbartitledisplaymode(_:)) is the alternative

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for letting me know. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I wasn’t clear enough, sorry for that. Actually I want the picture on the child screen on the top and not the navigation bar. In iOS 14.4 it wasn’t a problem, because when you open the child view and scroll down, the navigation bar would appear. In iOS 14.5 it looks like this behaviour is gone. The navigationbar pops out directly in the child view if the navigationbar is also visible in the parent view. When the navigation bar isn't visible in the parent view it works ok, because the picture is at the top in the child view. Hopefully my image shows this behaviour.

Comment: @SoftGuru I think the "open the child view and scroll down, the navigation bar would appear" behavior is still here: [gif (iOS 14.5)](https://github.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/blob/master/Screen%20Recording%202021-04-29%20at%208.44.08%20AM.gif?raw=true)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if you scroll down in the parent view (navigationbar showed up) and then click on the navigationlink, the navigationbar will be (pop out) shown also in the top op of the child view (without scrolling). I will try to add two extra pictures in the top. First one: parent view - without navigationbar pop out. Second one: parent view - navigationbar pop out (scroll down). I like to have always only the car picture on the top and when you scroll down the navigationbar appear.

Answer (score 0):

I added two pictures:
First one: parent view - without navigationbar pop out.
Second one: parent view - navigationbar pop out (scroll down).
I like to have always only the car picture on the top (on the edge) and when you scroll down the navigationbar appears.

[[image: Navigationbar issue][1]]
[image]

Comment: Ah, I see... you should move this back into your original question (just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67315955/edit) it). In iOS 14.5 there's probably something that keeps the navigation bar's display mode across pushed views. It might not be possible to change this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like an issue in iOS 14.5.